# How do I integrate $\int \sqrt{1+\sin(x)/(n)}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \sqrt{1+\sin(\frac{x}{n})}dx$

I tried it and I am stuck and have no idea how to solve this.
I tried substituting u as x/n, and then used half-angle formula, then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to math.se, this question will be recieved poorly since it does not meet the standards of asking a [good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{aligned}
\text { Let }
2 n y =\frac{n \pi}{2}-x, \text { then } \\
I &=-2 n \int \sqrt{1+\sin \left[\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}-2 n y\right)\right]} d y \\
&=-2 n \int \sqrt{1+\cos 2 y} d y \\
&=-2 n \int \sqrt{2 \cos ^{2} y} d y \\
&=-2 \sqrt{2} n \int \operatorname{sgn}(\cos y) \cos y d y \\
&=-2 \sqrt{2} n-\operatorname{sgn}(\cos y) \sin y+C \\
&=-2 \sqrt{2} n \operatorname{sgn}\left[\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2 n}\right)\right] \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{x}{2 n}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: yeah this is the answer precisely